# spliting a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to extract an article ID from the following href:

```
/MarketUpdate/Pricing/9352730
```

I just want to extract the ID at the end of the string and am using the following code:

```
    var $newsLink = $(this).attr('href');

    var $newsString = $newsLink.substr($newsLink.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

However this returns the final '/' which i do not want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var $newsString = $newsLink.substr($newsLink.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Note that your assumption here is that the `'/'` is present in the string and there's an ID after it. A safer way to do this check if there's a chance `'/'` might not be present or the ID is missing would be to check for it first using:

```
if ($newsLink.lastIndexOf('/') != -1 && $newsLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 < $newsLink.length) {
    var $newsString = $newsLink.substr($newsLink.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the `/` character by telling the `substr` call to start one character after the index, like this:

```
var $newsString = $newsLink.substr($newsLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```